# How to insert the new array values with previously inserted item at same array index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Lot of questions are available for `array push and splice` but not like this one.

Please see this fiddle for what i try
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwwzj/8/)

I have the output like this

```
[{"rup":"100","dol":"50"},{"rup":"100","dol":"50"},{"expense":   
[{"reason":0,"cost":0,"receipt":0,"expense_type":0}]},{"expense":  
[{"reason":1,"cost":1,"receipt":1,"expense_type":1}]}]
```

but what i need is

```
[{"rup":"100","dol":"50",{"expense":[{"reason":0,"cost":0,"receipt":0,"expense_type":0}},
{"rup":"100","dol":"50",{"expense":[{"reason":1,"cost":1,"receipt":1,"expense_type":1}}]
```

I tried `SPLICE() and ARRAY.INSERT()` methods but not get like above.

Please suggest any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this piece of code,

```
for (var i in costArray) {
    costArray[i].expense = expenseArray[i];
}
```

Out put:

```
[{"rup":"100","dol":"50","expense":{"reason":0,"cost":0,"receipt":0,"expense_type":0}},
{"rup":"100","dol":"50","expense":{"reason":1,"cost":1,"receipt":1,"expense_type":1}}]
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/7j2Nd/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The format you want in not valid in javascript, I guess you mean this:

```
{ "rup":"100","dol":"50", "expense":{"reason":0,"cost":0,"receipt":0,"expense_type":0} }
```

To get this, try replacing

```
 costArray.push({"expense":expenseArray});
```

with

```
costArray[i]["expense"] = expenseArray
```

in the second loop.